# win8 apache stops output

Tags: php, mysql, apache, windows-8.1

I have a PHP script that inserts 40.000 records into a MySQL table. Every 500 records there is an output in the browser. The scripts works perfect in Win7. In Win8.1 the output in the browser stops after about 20.000 inserts. The connection to the browser is not closed, it is still waiting for a response. The inserts into the table continue until about 33.000 inserts. This error only happens when I use a local domain which is on IP 127.0.0.2. On 127.0.0.1 everything is fine. I need different IP numbers because I have SSL certificates.

Comment: Please show us the script. We can't guess the problem.

Comment: this is the script used: http://donauweb.at/_win8test.phps